# How to apply CSS to a DialogBox using ClientBundle?

Tags: css, gwt

I'm trying to apply some CSS to my subclass of DialogBox via ClientBundle. When inspecting the DOM I can see an obfuscated class-name got added (class="gwt-DialogBox GF2AVPFBPD") but it does not bear/apply any propertes/changes...

```
class RegistrationDialog 
  extends DialogBox 
{
  interface MyClientBundle 
    extends ClientBundle 
  {
    @Source("regDlg.css")
    MyCssResource css();
  }

  interface MyCssResource 
    extends CssResource 
  {
    String registrationDialog();
  }

  MyClientBundle myClientBundle = GWT.create(MyClientBundle.class);

  RegistrationDialog()
  {
    add(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    addStyleName(myClientBundle.css().registrationDialog());
  }
  ...
```

regDlg.css:

```
.registrationDialog
{
  background-image: url("logo.png") !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  color: red !important;
  font-size: xx-large !important;
}
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: Which style has the higher priority - your or GWT's (`.gwt-DialogBox`)? Check it with Firebug or a similar tool to see if [GWT is not overriding your style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322779/gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style).

Comment: I did that. Like I said, I inspected the DOM, the properties are not listed. (Meaning not even listed as being disabled by another rule.) :( Thanks anyways, Igor.

Comment: If they are not listed, they might be getting pruned by Firefox/Firebug/whatever - the usual reason is a syntax error. Set the `CssResource.style` property to `pretty` in your module file to disable obfuscation for easier debugging :) `<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty" />`. See CssResource's [Lever and Knobs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Levers_and_Knobs).

Comment: Wouldn't Eclipse report an error? Anyways, I've set the CssResource.style to pretty and not the class is GO412LVPD-cz-mma-client-ui-LoginDialog-MyCssResource-registrationDialog. But still no properties applied. :(

Comment: Well I'm giving up for now, I will create a new project to make sure nothing else is interfering with the ClientBundle. Thanks for your time & effort, Igor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting to call CssResource.ensureInjected(). From the documentation;

*At runtime, call CssResource.ensureInjected() to inject the contents of the stylesheet.

- This method is safe to call multiple times, as subsequent invocations will be a no-op.

- The recommended pattern is to call ensureInjected() in the static initializer of your various widget types*

Check out the answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432232/gwt-uibinder-doesnt-load-the-stylesheet) for more code info.